# Macports uninstall only one Python version

Tags: python, uninstallation, macports

I have Macports and for historic reasons have multiple versions installed (2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6). How can I uninstall `python34` and all Python 3.4 packages?

---

That was my main question, here's some background info and things I've tried.

At first I did this:

```
$ sudo port uninstall python34
Password:
Note: It is not recommended to uninstall/deactivate a port that has dependents 
as it breaks the dependents.
The following ports will break:
 py34-six @1.10.0_0
 ... more packages here, all the ones starting with py34 that I want to remove ...
Continue? [y/N]:
```

Then I tried this, which to my big surprise / horror started to uninstall also Python packages from Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6:

```
$ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents python34
```

From `port help uninstall` I can see that there's an `@version` syntax and a `--no-exec` option.

But to be honest, from the description given it's not clear to me if / how `@version` applies to Python itself and Python packages in Macports (as far as I know `python34` and `python35` are separate ports, but `py34-something` and `py35-something` are different versions of the same port?

And `--no-exec` help says "Do not execute any stored pre- or post-uninstall procedures." What does this mean? Can I safely use it to list what will be uninstalled, or are there other phases or procedures during which it might or will uninstall something?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-y` for a dry run to see what will be uninstalled without actually performing the uninstallation:

```
port -y uninstall --follow-dependents python34
```

Comment: For me `port -y uninstall --follow-dependents python34` lists exactly the packages I do want to uninstall: https://gist.github.com/cdeil/9e1f47270b71844a8f618ec17d9134d6
But as I said above, without the `-y`, `port uninstall --follow-dependents python34` starts to uninstall other packages from Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 as well.
Do you see the same behaviour? Is it a bug in Macports?

Comment: No, I tried and it only uninstalled those listed as its dependents, nothing more. But I only have two versions. What other packages you observed that was also uninstalled?

Comment: This is what I got this time: https://gist.github.com/cdeil/dc6dd1029964542c6365c2fdde21e776
As you can see e.g. on line 130, `py35-bokeh` was uninstalled.
Is this a bug? Shouldn't the list of packages with `-y` and then the ones that are actually uninstalled when you leave `-y` off be identical?

Comment: I can duplicate the issue now when I add more ports. Looks like it's a bug. I tried uninstalling individual port from the list obtained by "-y" option one by one before uninstalling python34, and it worked without triggering any other python versions.

Comment: Jack: thank! Since you can reproduce the behaviour I see and also think it might be a bug, I've filed an issue at https://trac.macports.org/ticket/54645

Comment: @Christoph Thanks!